# How do I query for specific data in table A, and then compare a field in A to a field in table B?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm pretty new to SQL and have run into this issue: I want to get all the data from table A under a certain condition, and get data from table B based off of that same conditon's field.

The data I'm working with is job-sensitive, so I'll draw up an example table. Say Table A is a table of red playing cards (hearts and diamonds) with two fields:

```
|-----------+---------|  
| card_id   | type    |  
|-----------+---------|  
|     1     | heart   |
|-----------+---------| 
|     2     | heart   |
|-----------+---------|
|     3     | diamond |
|-----------+---------|  
|     4     | heart   |
|-----------+---------|
```

Let's say table B has the same exact structure, but is for black playing cards (clubs and spades).

```
|-----------+---------|  
| card_id   | type    |  
|-----------+---------|  
|     1     | club    |
|-----------+---------| 
|     2     | spade   |
|-----------+---------|
|     3     | spade   |
|-----------+---------|  
|     4     | club    |
|-----------+---------|
```

Now let's say that I want to select every card in A that is a heart, but whenever I find a heart, I also want to select every club in B.

I imagine the pseudocode would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b  
WHERE a.type = "heart"  
(and if tableA.type = "heart",  
also SELECT * in tableB where type = "club.")
```

What I would like to see output is the following

```
|-----------+---------|  
| card_id   | type    |  
|-----------+---------|  
|     1     | heart   |
|-----------+---------|  
|     1     | club    |
|-----------+---------| 
|     4     | club    |
|-----------+---------| 
|     2     | heart   |
|-----------+---------|  
|     1     | club    |
|-----------+---------| 
|     4     | club    |
|-----------+---------| 
|     4     | heart   |
|-----------+---------| 
|     1     | club    |
|-----------+---------| 
|     4     | club    |
|-----------+---------|
```

Sorry if this is an easy question, I can't find anything relating to this specific problem of mine.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want.

Comment: Is the order of the rows important?

Comment: Yes, they should look like that order

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to get the results you want. It takes a `UNION` of all the `hearts` in `tableA` with a copy of each of the `clubs` in `tableB` for each `heart` in tableA. The output is then ordered, first by the `card_id` of the `heart`, then by the source of the card (`tableA` or `tableB`) and finally by the actual `card_id`:

```
SELECT card_id, type
FROM (
  SELECT 'a' as tbl, card_id AS cid, card_id, type
  FROM tableA
  WHERE type = 'heart'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', a.card_id, b.card_id, b.type
  FROM tableA a
  JOIN tableB b ON a.type = 'heart' AND b.type = 'club'
) c
ORDER BY cid, tbl, card_id
```

Output:

```
card_id     type
1           heart
1           club
4           club
2           heart
1           club
4           club
4           heart
1           club
4           club
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZ7466FP48hrNSzN611BnE/0)